# Differentiating an equation

Tags: python, sympy

I want to differentiate the following equation

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()

x, t, r, phi = symbols('x, t, r, phi')

# this is how I want to do it
eq = Eq(x(t), r*phi(t))
eq.diff(t)
```

[image]

The result is differentiated only on the left side. I would like it to be evaluated on both sides. Is that possible in a simple way?

Currently I do the following:

```
Eq(eq.lhs.diff(t), eq.rhs.diff(t))
```

Comment: It's not actually applied to the left-hand side. That's just a printing issue. It's applied to the whole equality.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing some of the logic from [Sympy: working with equalities manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239565/sympy-working-with-equalities-manually), you can do something like this:

```
eq.func(*map(lambda x: diff(x, t), eq.args))
```

A bit ugly, but it works. Alternatively, you could just lift the `.do()` method from that and use it if you're going to want to do this a bunch of times.