# Doing operation to Equality objects in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way to do some operation to both sides of an equality object in sympy? For example is there a better way to do the following because it is annoying

```
eq1 = sym.Eq(2*x,5)
eq1 = sym.Eq(2* eq1.rhs, 2 * eq1.lhs)
```

I would think its like `eq1 * 2` but that does not work

Comment: Reread the sympy gotchas about "equality"  `eq1 = ...` is not doing what you think it does.  It simply assigns the RHS to the variable `eq1`.

Comment: I think I know what you are saying I will update my question so that it explains the issue better.

Comment: [This](https://awstip.com/customizing-pythons-sympy-for-easy-equation-manipulation-ca30b9d0dabf) may be helpful.

Comment: Use `a - b` instead of `Eq(a, b)` ? `2 * (a - b)` works wonder. What are you actually trying to achieve by multypling both hand sides of a equation?

Comment: @Lærne I am just trying to do some basic algebra and solve by myself

Comment: See related question and [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26957807/1089161).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is implemented on an external package, [Algebra with SymPy](https://github.com/gutow/Algebra_with_Sympy). You can install it with `pip install -U Algebra-with-SymPy`. Then, you can follow the documentation to learn all its feature. Instead of `Equality` it uses `Equation`.

Here are a couple of examples:

```py
from sympy import *
from algebra_with_sympy import *
var('a b c x')

# NOTE: Eqn is an alias for Equation
eq1=Eqn(a, b / c)
print(eq1)
# out: a = b/c          (eq1)
print(eq1 * c)
# out: a*c = b
print(c * eq1)
# out: a*c = b
print(exp(eq1))
# out: exp(a) = exp(b/c)
print(exp(log(eq1)))
# out: a = b/c          (eq1)

eq2 = Eqn(b / c + 2, x)
print(eq2)
# out: b/c + 2 = x          (eq2)
eq3 = eq2 - 2
print(eq3)
# out: b/c = x - 2          (eq3)
eq4 = eq1.subs(eq3)
print(eq4)
# out: a = x - 2          (eq4)
print(solve(eq4, x)[0])
# print: x = a + 2
```

The beautiful thing about this package is that you should be able to apply SymPy's functionalities on equations. Above you can see that:

- `exp(eq1)` the exponential function gets applied to both side of the equation.
- `solve` is able to return objects of type `Equation`
- the usual SymPy's expression manipulation functions (`simplify`, `collect`, ...) also works with `Equation`.